# Docker container with cron and flask app

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile

I am trying to configure a docker container with a cron job and a flask app.

It is just not working..

I am aware that each container must have only 1 CMD command, but what about

- RUN service cron start
- CMD python hello.py

Shouldn't it work?

ps: I am avoiding creating a separate image for the cron job for other reasons...

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y cron

COPY . .

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD ./cron_job/crontab /etc/cron.d/cron_job

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron_job

RUN service cron start

# hello.py => flask app
CMD python hello.py
```

Comment: and

CMD service cron start && python hello.py  ??

Answer (score 2):

Docker images do not save running processes. When your RUN command executes, it is only executed during the docker build phase and stops after the build completes.

You need to specify the service cron start in your CMD (entry point).

I would suggest creating a script to handle these tasks. As Containers were designed to only run a single process. But if you wrap your tasks in a single script and the script is the entry point you can get around this limitation.

```
CMD /start.sh
```

Where start.sh is a script that starts your cron service, and then runs your python script. You can also use supervisord but in my opinion for simple tasks like this, don't bother. In most cases don't bother with supervisord.

Reference for above explanation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/